# Passing ArrayList<T> between service and activity

Tags: android, service

I have a App this have a service this run STICKY if has work to do even if the user close the app the service work until finish her work.

Look i've followed the tutorial [Android Example: Communication between Activity and Service using Messaging](http://blog.philippheckel.com/2012/06/10/android-example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging/) and adapt to my app but when i try to send messages, this aren't receive by my service or client.

Also I need to pass arguments more complex like a ArrayList the workflow is like this

1. Users start my app and the app start the service
2. the user push a button in the app and the app sent signal to service (this can be a integer)
3. the service fetch data from internet, process and sent this data to app if is running if not the service notify to the user for new data
4. if after a while nothing is receive from the server the service stop.

The question is **how to pass complex objects between a service and an application?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass complex objects in a `Message` using [`setData(android.os.Bundle)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html#setData%28android.os.Bundle%29).  Bundles need [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) data so they can be serialised, but have support for ArrayLists of basic types (such as integers and strings) for convenience.  If your list contains custom objects, you will need to make them implement `Parcelable` and add them to your bundle using [`putParcelableArrayList(String key, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelableArrayList%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E%29).

If your data is quite complex/structured, you could also look into using a [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).  There is an initial learning curve but providers are well suited to some cases.